# How to iteratively bring a Dataframe back to the driver in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Main question: How do you safely (without risking crashing due to OOM) iterate over every row (guaranteed every row) in a dataframe from the driver node in Spark? I need to control how big the data is as it comes back, operate on it, and discard it to retrieve the next batch (say 1000 rows at a time or something)

I am trying to safaely and iteratively bring the data in a potentially large Dataframe back to the driver program so that I may use the data to perform HTTP calls. I have been attempting use `someDf.foreachPartition{makeApiCall(_)}` and allowing the Executors to handle the calls. It works - but debugging and handling errors has proven to be pretty difficult when launching in prod envs, especially on failed calls.

I know there is `someDf.collect()` action, which brings ALL the data back to the driver all at once. However, this solution is not suggested, because if you have a very large DF, you risk crashing the driver.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check df.toLocalIterator: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the data does not fit into memory, you could use something like :

```
df.toLocalIterator().forEachRemaining( row => {makeAPICall(row)})
```

but `toLocalIterator` has considerable overhead compared to `collect`

Or you can collect your dataframe batch-wise (which does essentially the same as `toLocalIterator`):

```
val partitions = df.rdd.partitions.map(_.index)   
partitions.toStream.foreach(i => df.where(spark_partition_id() === lit(i)).collect().map(row => makeAPICall(row)))
```

Comment: Getting data by partition doesn't guarantee prevention of OOM as the partition can be big and memory can be small.

Comment: @Salim but you have control over the number of partitions, so OOM CAN be prevented

Comment: I agree with you, at the sometime I am trying to discourage having a biodata application depending on driver node so much.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth is there any particular reason you invoked `toStream` as opposed to something like `toSeq` ? Since it's partitions we're dealing with, the number is finite, and likely less than 1000 .

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to bring all that data back to driver because driver is just 1 node and it will become the bottleneck. The scalability will be lost. If you had to do this then think twice if you really need a big data application? probably not.

`dataframe.collect()` is the best way to bring the data to driver and it will bring all data. The alternative is `toLocalIterator` which will bring data of the largest partition which can be big too. So this should be rarely used and for small amount of data only.

If you insist then you can write the output to a file or queue and read that file in a controlled manner. This will be partially scalable solution which I won't prefer.